# linked list implementation in C

Tags: c, insert, linked-list

In the following code for a linked list implementation, I am getting the error  `cannot convert node_type to node * for argument 1 to 'node *insert(node *)'`. I don't understand this message. Basically the program is not able to call the function `insert` from `main()`.

Can anyone help explain this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node_type
{
    int data;
    node_type *next;
};

typedef struct node_type node;

node  *insert(node *head);
void print1(node *temp);

int main(void){
    int dat;
    char x,ch;

    node *temp;


    temp=NULL;
    printf("do u wanna enter a new node? \n");
    scanf("%c", &x);
    if (x=='y' or x=='Y'){

        temp=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("enter the data: \n");
        scanf("%d ", &dat);

        temp->data= dat;
        temp->next = NULL;
    }

    printf("do u want to insert another element?\n");
    scanf("%c ", &ch);
    if( ch=='y' or ch=='Y'){
        insert(temp);
    }
    print1(temp);

    getch();

}
node *insert(node *temp)
{
    int dat;
    char ch1;
    node *newnode;

    newnode=(node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    printf("enter the data: ");
    scanf("%d", &dat);
    newnode->data=dat;
    newnode->next=temp;
    temp=newnode;

    printf("do u want to insert another element?\n");
    scanf("%c ", &ch1);
    if( ch1=='y' or ch1=='Y'){
        insert(temp);
    }
    else return temp;

}
void print1(node *temp)
{
    int t;

    while(temp!= NULL){
        t= temp->data;
        temp= temp->next;
        printf(" %d ", t);
    }
}
```

Comment: In strict C, the structure definition won't compile.  If compiled with a C++ compiler, it will compile.  Since you're using `<conio.h>`, you're probably using MS Visual C++, and I'd guess your code is being compiled as C++ rather than C.

Answer (score 1):

A few problems in your code:

1. The definition of `struct node_type`

   ```
   struct node_type
   {
       int data;
       node_type *next;
   };
   ```

   is not right according to C syntax, type `node_type` does not exist before the `typedef struct node_type node;` statement.

   To fix this, you could

   a) define `struct node_type` like this

   ```
   struct node_type
   {
       int data;
       struct node_type *next;
   };
   ```

   or

   b) use (Thanks @yongzhy)

   ```
   typedef struct node_type
   {
       int data;
       struct node_type *next;
   };
   ```

   or

   c) compile your code with a C++ compiler. (Thanks @JonathanLeffler)
2. All these

   ```
   if (x=='y' or x=='Y'){
   ```

   should be replaced by

   ```
   if (x=='y' || x=='Y'){
   ```

   or you could just include `<iso646.h>`, which includes `#define or ||` in it (Thanks @JonathanLeffler),

   or you should compile your code with a C++ compiler.

Comment: Or the code should include `<iso646.h>` so that `or` etc are handled (defined: `#define or ||` or equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

add to @leeduhem

```
typedef struct node_type
{
    int data;
    struct node_type *next;
} node;
```

this will void additional line of

```
typedef struct node_type node;
```